# Confused by the opts : OptionsPattern[ ] pattern

Tags: programming, pattern-matching, options, argument-patterns, optional-arguments

I'm trying to make sense of the syntax in the clause `opts:OptionsPattern[]`, as found in this standard "rule-based" (pseudo-)function definition pattern:

```
aFunction[a1_, a2_, a3_, opts:OptionsPattern[]] := ...
```

I've spent the last couple of hours chasing one reference after another in the *Mathematica* documentation, and getting nowhere.  In fact, I now have a few more questions than the ones I began with (and remain unanswered).

Let me try to distill all these questions into two.

**First**, does `:` have a unique, consistent interpretation?  If it does I can't figure it out.  It seems to have a completely different meaning depending on the context.  Here's a stark illustration: suppose that `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` are unbound symbols.  Then, of the following expressions, the first three are valid, but the last one is not (i.e. the front end throws an exception):

```
    b : c : d
    b :(c : d)
a :(b : c): d
   (b : c): d
```

I was not prepared for this!  (At worst, I expected non-associativity, as found with the `-` or `/` operators, for example; IOW, at worst I expected that `(b:c):d` would be merely different from `b:(c:d)`, not that it would throw an exception.)

**Second**, is the syntax of `opts:OptionsPattern[]`

```
aFunction[a1_, a2_, a3_, opts:OptionsPattern[]] := ...
```

a *special form* (i.e. not deducible from any other syntactic rule in the language)?  It appears so to me, because I cannot produce any useful expressions with the *symbol:defaultValue* pattern among the formal arguments of a "rule-based" (pseudo-)function definition<sup>1</sup>.

So a different way to formulate the second question is: is there any useful application of the form

```
aFunction[..., symbol:defaultValue] := ...
```

...in which *defaultValue* is something *other* than `OptionsPattern[]`?

Note: I know the use-case for the similar-looking form (note the `_`)

```
aFunction[..., symbol_:defaultValue] := ...
```

I'm not asking about it.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> For example:</sub>

```
foo[x:8] := x;

foo[]
(* foo[] *)

foo[3]
(* foo[3] *)
```

<sub>Contrast the "do-nothing" definition above with this one:</sub>

```
frobozz[x:OptionsPattern[]] := x;

frobozz[]
(* Sequence[] *)

frobozz[1]
(* frobozz[1] *)

frobozz[quux->frobnitz]
(* quux->frobnitz *)
```

Comment: related [question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17358/3066). Has a particularly good answer by Leonid Shifrin.

Comment: Basically, you are right in thinking `OptionPattern` has non-standard semantics and colon ( : ) has context sensitive semantics.

Comment: Re `a:b:c`, the uses are in fact different. the one on the left gives a name to a pattern. The one on the right gives it an optional value. I agree there is a semblance to context sensitivity and I also am not so happy with that. To see it more starkly, compare these three: `FullForm[a : b]`, `FullForm[_ : b]`, and `FullForm[a : b : c]`. The "colon-b" parsing is not, strictly speaking, context sensitive. But it sure tries its best to be coy about that fact. Finicky too, about when it will even parse: check `FullForm[c[a] : b]`.

Comment: For the second part, if the behavior of `Log[Exp[y]]` has ever seemed too pedagogical for you, maybe the definition `log[y:Exp[x_]] := x` could be useful?

Comment: "a particularly good answer by Leonid Shifrin" - note to newcomers: this is redundant.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Re 1: As documented in [Operator Input Forms](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OperatorInputForms.html), colon represents two different operations:

```
symb:expr   Pattern[symb, expr]
patt:expr   Optional[patt, expr]
```

If you look at the `FullForm` of your first three examples, you'll see that they follow these forms.  The fourth example arguably is a bug.

Re 2)  No, `opts:OptionsPattern[]` is not a special form. From the rules given above, rules `opts: OptionsPattern[]` is the first case, assigning the pattern `OptionsPattern[]` to the symbol `opts`.  `OptionsPattern[]` is itself a particular kind of pattern, just like `_`, `Except`, and `KeyValuePattern` are particular kinds of patterns.  What sets it slightly apart from other patterns is that it sets up special rules for using `OptionValue` on the RHS of the rule.

More generally, about a year and half ago (so I think for 10.4), I got so fed up with the documentation of `OptionsPattern` and `OptionsValue` that I led a mini project to completely rewrite their pages.  I think reading both the details and the new examples will give you a lot more insight into this idiom.